# Multiple choice question on upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ upper triangular matrix with complex entries. Pick
>   out the true statement(s):
>
> $(a)$ If $A \neq 0$, and if $a_{ii} = 0$, for all $1\leq i \leq n$, then $A^n = 0$.
>
> $(b)$ If $A \neq I$ and if $a_{ii} = 1$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$, then $A$ is not diagonalizable.
>
> $(c)$ If $A \neq 0$, then $A$ is invertible.

$(a)$ is true as eigenvalues of the upper triangular matrices are diagonal elements and here all the eigenvalues are $0$. Hence $x^n=0$ is the characteristic equation and by Cayley-Hamilton theorem $A^n=0$.

I have no idea about $(b)$.

$(c)$ is not true.

Answer (score 1):

For (b), consider the minimal polynomial of the matrix. Its characteristic polynomial is plainly $(x-1)^n$. So what must its minimal polynomial be if it is to be diagonalisable? Can its minimal polynomial be this?

**Hint 1** (mouse-over to reveal):

> A matrix is diagonalisable if and only if its minimal polynomial has distinct linear factors.

**Hint 2**:

> The minimal polynomial of a matrix divides its characteristic polynomial.

**Hint 3**:

> A matrix satisfies its own minimal polynomial.

Comment: is there any result that "a matrix is diagonalizable iff minimal polynomial have distinct linear factor". if it is true then b is false.

Comment: @mintu: See **Hint 1** above.

Comment: then x-1 is not the minimal polynomial and hence it is not diagonalizable. am i right?

Comment: @mintu: Correct!

Answer (score 0):

Part (b) is actually the easiest one among all three. **Hint:** if $A$ is diagonalizable, what would be the diagonal matrix it is similar to?